# Add registry key via batchfile for Edge

Tags: windows, batch

been trying to create a new folder in the registry called "EdgeUpdate" with a DWORD named "DoNotUpdateToEdgeWithChromium" and data 1. I have this so far, i was able to get it working but realized i had the wrong path. When i updated the path to the desired location i still hasn't updated. I got myself lost.

https://www.thewindowsclub.com/run-legacy-edge-and-chromium-edge

REG ADD "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\EdgeUpdate" /v DoNotUpdateToEdgeWithChromium /t REG_DWORD /d 1

Comment: IE and Legacy Edge will be gone in six months. It is not worth any effort to prevent the update.  https://www.techrepublic.com/article/microsoft-this-is-when-ie11-and-legacy-edge-support-ends/#:~:text=Naturally%2C%20this%20means%20legacy%20Edge,ending%20support%20for%20the%20browser.

Comment: @John - It's already gone.  20H2 already comes with Chromium Edge.  It's not even possible to have a Side By Side install of Legacy Edge (20H2 ignores the group policy)

Comment: Yes, but some (maybe as many as 1/2 of people) are on old systems and still have these old browsers. So while you are correct with respect to 20H2, I was commenting on older systems.